# How to get distinct record postgresql with union

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am fetching an record which has two type of status i.e active and inactive and we can have many inactive status but only one active status in table at a time so I want all records with active and all inactive record except active.

table record:-

```
id  |  status  | status_message  | csr_id  
-----+----------+-----------------
 139 | inactive | Hi             |  1
 138 | inactive | Test campaigin |  1
 134 | inactive | Test           |  1
 142 | inactive | Test ctr group |  2
 143 | inactive | test 3         |  2
 144 | inactive | test 3         |  2
 145 | inactive | test 3         |  2
 146 | inactive | test 8         |  2
 147 | inactive | Itf            |  2
 148 | inactive | test 9         |  2
 149 | inactive | Test evry1     |  2
 150 | active   | Test live cmrt1|  1
```

query for your reference

```
 (select * from profile where csr_id IN (2,1) AND status = 'active') 
    UNION 
 (select DISTINCT ON (csr_id) *from profile where csr_id IN (2,1) AND status = 'inactive') order by status;
```

Result:-

```
id  |  status  | status_message | csr_id |
-----+----------+---------------+--------
150 | active   | test 9         |  1
134 | inactive | Test cmtt      |  1
```

Expected result:-

```
id  |  status  | status_message | csr_id |
-----+----------+---------------+--------
150 | active   | test 9         |  1
```

Any solution ?

Comment: That is unclear. Do you want all active **and** all inactive in one query? Then why not just omit the second `WHERE` condition?

Comment: there are n no of profile present in db where csr_id is user_id, I shown example of only one profile  , when user log in then I make entry here and make status active and when log out then update active to inactive

and if try to log in again then create new record with status active 

now in second case I want active record and neglate inactive one for that csr_id.
got?

Comment: and if no active status present then return last inactive id, but not both at a time

Comment: I removed the conflicting version tags (of unsupported Postgres version). Please add only **one** tag indicating the version you are really using.

Comment: What happens when a user logs in then opens a new tab on their browser  and logs in again without logging out of the first?